# MySQL 5.6.34 keep eating all the RAM

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, memory

I have 2 servers (master-slave) with Centos 7.3 (64 GB RAM) and MySQL Server 5.6.34 installed. MySQL keeps using more and more RAM; what I've been doing is stop/start MySQL so it releases the memory, before my SO kills it. Here's a graph of one of them (the master)

[image: Memory Consumption]

I've done minor changes in my.cnf to "help" using less memory, but it keeps going up always. Searched the web to find if there's a memory problem with this version but found nothing. One thins that it's mentioned in the changelog to 5.6.35 (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-35.html) is:

> InnoDB: InnoDB failed to free memory used by the full-text optimizer
>   thread. (Bug #24331265)

but I'm not using full-text indexes:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM information_schema.innodb_ft_config;    
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Some support in Rackspace recommended me to use jemalloc (For other reasons; there were performance issues with replication); so it was configured:

```
#vim /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service
Environment="LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib64/libjemalloc.so.1"
```

And was running with that until May, 31 (the last restart in the graphic); when I removed it, hoping it was the cause, but today I found that the server once again is using 94% of my memory. Here's my cnf:

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8

[mysqld]

## General
ignore-db-dir                        = lost+found
datadir                              = /var/lib/mysql
socket                               = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
tmpdir                               = /var/lib/mysql/mysqltmp
port                                 = 3307

## Cache
table-definition-cache               = 4096
table-open-cache                     = 4096
thread-cache-size                    = 50

## Per-thread Buffers
join-buffer-size                     = 2M
read-buffer-size                     = 2M
read-rnd-buffer-size                 = 2M
sort-buffer-size                     = 2M

## Networking
interactive-timeout                  = 600
max-connections                      = 250
max-connect-errors                   = 1000000
max-allowed-packet                   = 16M
wait-timeout                         = 600

## MyISAM
key-buffer-size                      = 256M
myisam-sort-buffer-size              = 128M

## InnoDB
innodb-buffer-pool-size              = 35G
innodb-file-format                   = Barracuda
innodb-file-per-table                = 0
innodb-log-file-size                 = 512M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances         = 16

## Replication and PITR
binlog-format                        = MIXED
expire-logs-days                     = 2
log-bin                              = /var/lib/binlogs/fab65-bin.log
log-slave-updates                    = TRUE
read-only                            = 0
relay-log                            = /var/lib/binlogs/relay3309-log
relay-log-space-limit                = 16G
server-id                            = 65

gtid-mode                = ON
enforce-gtid-consistency         = TRUE

master-info-repository           = TABLE
relay-log-info-repository        = TABLE
sync-master-info             = 1

report-host              = fab65
report-port              = 3307

#Cambiar la codificacion de la DB
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_general_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'

# Controls whether stored function creators can be trusted not to create stored functions that will cause unsafe events to be written to the binary log.
log-bin-trust-function-creators

# Increase the group_concat_max
group_concat_max_len             = 1M

# Modify path for secure load_file
secure_file_priv = '/var/backup'

[mysqld_safe]
log-error                            = /var/log/mysqld.log
open-files-limit                     = 65535

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8
no-auto-rehash
```